# SWT FileDialog: Selecting directories instead of files

Tags: java, swt

Can I use the SWT [`FileDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html) to select folders instead of files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the [`DirectoryDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDirectoryDialog.html) instead. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DirectoryDialogpromptforadirectory.htm) is some sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.open();
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
    dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\"); // Windows specific
    System.out.println("RESULT=" + dialog.open());
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratestheDirectoryDialogclass.htm) is a slightly larger example.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RElvM.png) dialog instead? As it is a much more friendly ui

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately, no. SWT really is lacking in that regard

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the info