# How to select all files in a FileDialog?

Tags: java, linux, awt, filedialog

I want to select all files to exclude them from being displayed in my FileDialog.

```
        FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, "Some Title", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileDialog.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if(name.endsWith(".*")) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    fileDialog.setVisible(true);
```

In my code you can see, that I am trying to to that with the String ".*", to select all files. This doesn't work however and I don't know why.
I only want to show directories.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you get as result out of this?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude all files? Do you just want to show directories?

Comment: It just shows everything, files and directories. I think the "*"-operator is not working inside the string.

Comment: @copeg Yes, I only want to show directories.

Comment: [`return dir.isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)

Comment: Well, endsWith accepts a String literal, not a regular expression. What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWT FileDialog: Selecting directories instead of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140884/swt-filedialog-selecting-directories-instead-of-files)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Oh my, you are right! Thanks man! I totally misunderstood how the accept-method works! I was trying to `return dir.isDirectory()` before!

Comment: 'Yes, I only want to show directories', that is information that should have been included in your question

Comment: @copeg I added that, your answer still remains wrong though.

Comment: Why use the AWT based `FileDialog` when the Swing based `JFileChooser` is much better, **and** has a method to limit the selectable file to be a directory (ad not even show files)!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Because it doesn't look native on Linux/Mac, whereas FileDialog does. Read it up, it's very common to use it on other os-es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated, I found the answer to this question with the help of @JigarJoshi.

This is the working code to show ONLY Directories on a AWT FileDialog:

```
fileDialog.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return dir.isFile();
    }
});
```

*Please note that using FileDialog over JFileChooser is only recommendet, if you are on a non-Windows system. However on Mac and Linux, you should prefer to use FileDialog since it looks more native.*

Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JFileChooser, using a [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) to check the File object to see if it is a directory

```
  @Override
  public boolean accept( File file ) {
    return file.isDirectory();
  }
```

A FileDialog's FileFilter should work similarly. Also note the API for the [FileDialog's setFileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setFilenameFilter%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) method:

> "Filename filters do not function in Sun's reference implementation for Microsoft Windows."

Comment: You also misunderstood how the method works :) It is `return file.isFile()`

Comment: `Yes, I only want to show directories`. Using _return file.isDirectory()_ will only show directories. Using _return file.isFile()_ will only show files. Which is it?

Comment: No, because FileDialog.setFilenameFilter() requires a FileNAMEFilter, not a FileFilter. This FileNameFilter works different, because the "File" it expects in the "accept"-Method is actually a directory. Thats why I got confused at first, too.

Comment: I know about the API warning, but I am on Linux, so I cant be bothered. Still, your answer ist wrong..