# Selecting a directory

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

Is there any way to use the FileDialog to select a directory instead of just a file?

I am aware of this [SWT FileDialog: Selecting directories instead of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140884/swt-filedialog-selecting-directories-instead-of-files). But in the latest version of Eclipse (2018-09 4.9) a file selection dialog is used in a place where the DirectoryDialog was usually used (Project Explorer | Import | Existing Maven Project | Browse). I would really like to use this dialog instead of the DirectoryDialog.

[image]

Comment: That just looks like `DirectoryDialog` to me.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the dialog I meant.

Comment: That still looks like DirectoryDialog, since this dialog uses the native directory control it looks very different on the different platforms.

Comment: Yes, this is the new `DirectoryDialog` (since Eclipse 4.8): https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#windows-modern-directory-dialog

Comment: Ok thank you. I was still using Eclipse 4.7, so I cound not see the new dialog.